# Warning message "no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf" in data.table groupingsets

Tags: r, data.table

I am testing `data.table::groupingsets` and I keep getting an unexpected warning.

First, I create a data table to use as an input:

```
## create "long" iris data set
long_iris <-melt(as.data.table(iris),
                 measure.vars = c('Sepal.Width', 'Sepal.Length', 'Petal.Width', 'Petal.Length'),
                 id.vars = 'Species',
                 variable.factor = FALSE,
                 value.factor = FALSE)
```

then i pass it as an argument to `groupingsets`:

```
groupingsets(long_iris, 
             .(N = .N,
               Min = min(value),
               Max = max(value),
               Mean = mean(value), 
               SD = sd(value)),
             by = c('Species', 'variable'),
             ## group by 'variable' and 'Species' separately as well as the interaction, plus the overall stats (character())
             sets = list('variable', 'Species', c('variable', 'Species'), character()))
```

and the result looks OK

```
       Species     variable   N Min Max     Mean        SD
 1:       <NA>  Sepal.Width 150 2.0 4.4 3.057333 0.4358663
 2:       <NA> Sepal.Length 150 4.3 7.9 5.843333 0.8280661
 3:       <NA>  Petal.Width 150 0.1 2.5 1.199333 0.7622377
 4:       <NA> Petal.Length 150 1.0 6.9 3.758000 1.7652982
 5:     setosa         <NA> 200 0.1 5.8 2.535500 1.8483429
 6: versicolor         <NA> 200 1.0 7.0 3.573000 1.7623850
 7:  virginica         <NA> 200 1.4 7.9 4.285000 1.9153899
 8:     setosa  Sepal.Width  50 2.3 4.4 3.428000 0.3790644
 9: versicolor  Sepal.Width  50 2.0 3.4 2.770000 0.3137983
10:  virginica  Sepal.Width  50 2.2 3.8 2.974000 0.3224966
11:     setosa Sepal.Length  50 4.3 5.8 5.006000 0.3524897
12: versicolor Sepal.Length  50 4.9 7.0 5.936000 0.5161711
13:  virginica Sepal.Length  50 4.9 7.9 6.588000 0.6358796
14:     setosa  Petal.Width  50 0.1 0.6 0.246000 0.1053856
15: versicolor  Petal.Width  50 1.0 1.8 1.326000 0.1977527
16:  virginica  Petal.Width  50 1.4 2.5 2.026000 0.2746501
17:     setosa Petal.Length  50 1.0 1.9 1.462000 0.1736640
18: versicolor Petal.Length  50 3.0 5.1 4.260000 0.4699110
19:  virginica Petal.Length  50 4.5 6.9 5.552000 0.5518947
20:       <NA>         <NA> 600 0.1 7.9 3.464500 1.9754900
```

but i also get the following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In min(value) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(value) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I am using the iris data frame, so there are no missing values. I know that these errors often caused by passing a 0-length vector to `min` or `max` but I don't see how that's happening here.

I get the expected result, but I do not understand why I am getting this warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *suspect* that this is to find the classes of a row, so we'll at least return *something*. This is somewhat encouraged by finding this in the [source](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/groupingsets.R#L78):

```
  empty = if (length(.SDcols)) x[0L, eval(jj), by, .SDcols=.SDcols] else x[0L, eval(jj), by]
```

*Edit*: from @jangorecki, a long-time contributor to `data.table`. Thanks for chiming in!

> *It is to create template DT to which other groupings are rbinded*

Which is slightly more than what I initially suspected, though I think I was fairly close :-)

---

Let's provide a debugging function to the grouping:

```r
groupingsets(long_iris, 
             .(N = .N, Max = (function(z) { browser(); max(value); })(value)),
             by = c('Species', 'variable'),
             ## group by 'variable' and 'Species' separately as well as the interaction, plus the overall stats (character())
             sets = list(character(), 'variable', 'Species', c('variable', 'Species')))
```

In the first instantiation of this, let's look at `where` and the first couple of functions on the stack:

```r
Browse[2]> where
where 1: (function(z) {
    browser()
    max(value)
})(value)
where 2: `[.data.table`(x, 0L, eval(jj), by)
where 3: x[0L, eval(jj), by]
```

and the second iteration

```r
Browse[2]> c
Browse[2]> where
where 1: (function(z) {
    browser()
    max(value)
})(value)
where 2: eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame())
where 3: eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame())
```

Notice that on the first call, we see `x[0L, eval(jj), by]`, which is intentionally calling with a 0-row frame.

This doesn't occur with `sum`, likely because they behave somewhat differently in the face of no data:

```r
min()
# Warning in min() : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
# [1] Inf
sum()
# [1] 0
```

If you know functions you'll be using are noisy with empty data (like `min` and `max`), you can always suppress them or define empty-friendly versions that have reasonable defaults (such as `-Inf` for `max`, and `Inf` for `min`):

```r
max2 <- function(x, ...) max(c(-Inf, x), ...)
```

then it is not noisy:

```r
groupingsets(long_iris, 
             .(N = .N, Max = max2(value)),
             by = c('Species', 'variable'),
             sets = list(character(), 'variable', 'Species', c('variable', 'Species')))
#        Species     variable     N   Max
#         <fctr>       <char> <int> <num>
#  1:       <NA>         <NA>   600   7.9
#  2:       <NA>  Sepal.Width   150   4.4
#  3:       <NA> Sepal.Length   150   7.9
#  4:       <NA>  Petal.Width   150   2.5
#  5:       <NA> Petal.Length   150   6.9
#  6:     setosa         <NA>   200   5.8
#  7: versicolor         <NA>   200   7.0
#  8:  virginica         <NA>   200   7.9
#  9:     setosa  Sepal.Width    50   4.4
# 10: versicolor  Sepal.Width    50   3.4
# 11:  virginica  Sepal.Width    50   3.8
# 12:     setosa Sepal.Length    50   5.8
# 13: versicolor Sepal.Length    50   7.0
# 14:  virginica Sepal.Length    50   7.9
# 15:     setosa  Petal.Width    50   0.6
# 16: versicolor  Petal.Width    50   1.8
# 17:  virginica  Petal.Width    50   2.5
# 18:     setosa Petal.Length    50   1.9
# 19: versicolor Petal.Length    50   5.1
# 20:  virginica Petal.Length    50   6.9
#        Species     variable     N   Max
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed exploration and information! 

Is there any reason that it would be better to define alternative functions like `max2` instead of just supplying `Inf` and `-Inf` as arguments to the base `min` and `max` functions like `Max = max(-Inf, value)` and `Min = min(Inf, value)`? I tested it and it worked, but I'm curious if there's some larger "best practices" principle here.

Comment: Nope, that's perfectly fine as well, no need to get fancy with it. Glad it helped.

Comment: It is to create template DT to which other groupings are rbinded